# что значит PHP_ORIG_SCRIPT в SpamAssasin

Tags: email, spamassasin

Что означает параметр PHP_ORIG_SCRIPT в SpamAssasin. Из-за него теряю 2 пункта рейтинга. И самое главное как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это письма, отправленные php-функцией `mail`. У них в заголовках стоит

```
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 80:имяскрипта.php
```

Spam-Assassin выставляет им 2.5 балла, считая ботами

Если вы отправляете письма, то уберите заголовок или отправляйте через нормальный smtp-сервер.

Если вы получатель и хотите пропускать такие письма, то можете понизить балл в файле local.cf spamAssassin'a, установив нужную цифру или 0 для отмены правила:

```
score PHP_ORIG_SCRIPT 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас стоит exim, то в файле конфигурации,у меня на centOs он расположен etc/exim/exim.conf, открываем этот файл текстовым редактором и после 
remote_smtp:
  driver = smtp добавьте строчку  headers_remove = X-PHP-Originating- 
   Script должно получится так:

```
#remote_smtp:
#driver = smtp
#headers_remove = X-PHP-Originating-Script
```

## Только уберите решотки!

Сохраняем файл и перезагружаем exim.